# How do you get month number from UTC time for a specific timezone with a DateTime object?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have the end of the year (12/31/2017) for the EST timezone stored in UTC in a DateTime object.  When I get the Month property it's 1 because it's store in UTC and the end of the year in EST when converted UTC is 01/01/2018 04:59:59.

How can I convert this date into the correct timezone using the America/New_York timezone to get the correct month number for that timezone?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Noda to handle the conversion for me.

```
using NodaTime;
//Get the correct timezone
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb ["America/New_York"];
//Convert to the correct month
var month = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(endOfYear.ToUniversalTime()).InZone(zone.Month);
Console.Write(endOfYear.Month); //1 Not expected value
Console.Write(month); // 12 expected value
```